# How to catch return value from python script run in ipython3 notebook?

Tags: python, ipython, wolfram-mathematica, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to access Mathematica from an ipython3 notebook. So far i can run Mathematica commands using an python script from terminal. I followed these links: [github](https://github.com/Danilo-Araujo-Silva/Mathematica), [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4643/how-to-use-mathematica-functions-in-python-programs). I already found out, that it is possible to run python scripts in an ipython3 notebook using magic commands. The big question now is how to i call such a script, pass arguments i.e. Mathematica commands to it and most important of all catch the output?

So far the script seems to execute but i get not return whatsoever.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Okay so what seems to work is the following. The python script that runs the mathematica command originally contains the following

```
from subprocess import *
from sys import *

command='../mathematica/proxy.m'
parameter=argv[1]

call([command,parameter])
```

Now changing the last line to `output = check_output([command,parameter])` will store the byte that is returned in `output`. For my purposes I will convert this to a string and then to python array (I expect Mathematica to return an array). In the same way I pass any Mathematica command as a string to `parameter`.

Maybe this still helps someone.